# How to build a Laravel relationship between these entities?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have three tables in my database: `Users`, `Books`, and `Reading`. The structure of `Reading` is:

> id, user_id, book_id

Now, I need to access to all the books that the user is reading.

First, I would like to know which kind of relationship is, one to many, many to many, Has Many Through, etc. And what do I have to specify in each model? I mean, in the users model `hasMany('Reading')` or whatever.

I want to access with something like this: `Auth::user()->reading()->books()->get()` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of relationship where one `User` can be reading several books and one `Book` can be read by many users is `Many-to-Many` relationship.

So, to define such a relation in Laravel you should use `belongsToMany` method:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    function books()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany("Book", "Reading", "user_id", "book_id");
    }
}

class Book extends Eloquent
{
    function users()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany("User", "Reading", "book_id", "user_id");
    }
}

$books = Auth::user()->books;
```

Notice, you don't need to call method `->books()` but use a property `->books`, otherwise you'd have to call it like `Auth::user()->books()->get()`.

Comment: And how can I obtain all the ids, of the books without use a foreach, using something like Auth::user()->books->id;

Comment: `Auth::user()->books()->lists('id')` will return an array of book ids